# Can I transfer my left over annual leave to a new company?

Tags: germany, vacation

I will be quitting Company A on May 31st and I will be having a total of 11.5days leaves until 31st May.
I do not want to get compensated for these leaves and want to take over to my next Company B joining on 1st June.
Can I ask Company A to provide me **urlaubsbescheinigung** and submit in Company B?
Is this acceptable in Germany?
Note: I do not want to take the compensation in terms of cash for 11.5days and want to take all the leaves at the end of the year as 1 long vacation.

Comment: The question got me looking for our laws and interestingly in Switzerland the company can force you to take your vacation during your notice period if you are the one quitting the job. If they let you go its different because it is assumed you need to be looking for a new job which wouldnt make your vacation very relaxing so they generally cant force you to take the vacation :)

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Do I understand it correctly that if I hire someone I always have to assume that I still need to give them a whole years vacation in whatever time he has left in the year in my company and assume he will bring a Bescheinigung he has not had any vacation so far?

Comment: In my case, I have a total of 12.5 granted during the period Jan-May2022 and I have taken only 1 leave and I have remaining 11.5leaves. My question is can I carry forward 11.5 leaves to my new employer?

Answer (score 12):

The answer depends on the country/jurisdiction. In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) specifically:

Yes, this is possible in some cases - but as in many legal areas, the details are complicated.

The basic rules:

- If you are leaving the employment (no matter why), your employer must allow you to use your remaining vacation days. If that is not possible (because there is too little time left, or the company wants you to continue working), they must pay you for it, at your normal salary rate. However, that choice is up to the company - they can require you to take the days instead of receiving money.
- If you leave during the first half of the year (like in your case), you are entitled to a pro-rated number of vacation days (leaving end of April = 1/3 of the year = 1/3 of vacation days). If you leave during the second half (and have been employed for at least six months), you are entitled to the full amount of days mandated by law (20 days, according to "Mindesturlaubsgesetz").
- Even if your entitlement is pro-rated as explained above, if you have already taken more holiday than your entitlement (because of the pro-rating), the employer cannot ask for repayment. However, this "excess" reduces your vacation entitlement at your new employer.
- If you leave during the first half of the year, you are not entitled to "transfer" vacation days to your new employer - however, you will be entitled to a pro-rated number of vacation days at your new employer (and likewise with your old employer). If you leave during the second half, you are entitled to take the remaining vacation days with the new employer - for this you need a certificate from your old employer ("Urlaubsbescheinigung") declaring how many vacation days you took.

Note that these rules mostly only apply to the **legal minimum** - which is 20 working days (24 if you work a six-day week). If you get more vacation days (which is common), these extra vacation days may be subject to different rules, so check your emplyoment contract.

More reading (German):

- [Resturlaub bei Kündigung](https://www.advocado.de/ratgeber/arbeitsrecht/urlaub/resturlaub-bei-kuendigung.html)
- [Ausscheiden im zweiten Halbjahr: Anspruch auf vollen Jahresurlaub?](https://www.dahag.de/c/ebs/arbeitsrecht/ausscheiden-im-zweiten-halbjahr-anspruch-auf-vollen-jahresurlaub-1511)

---

On a **practical note**: While the above are the legal rules, you can always come to an individual agreement. It is not uncommon to ask for accomodation when negotiating a new job - if you have holiday plans, you can ask for extra (possibly unpaid) leave, and you can also ask to take vacation days during the first six months in the new job (which is usually not allowed). Just ask them.

Comment: "you are entitled to the full amount of days mandated by law (20 days)": other sources say you are entitled to the full amount, **unless the contract (Arbeitsvertrag) says otherwise** (e.g. https://gks-rechtsanwaelte.de/aktuelles/kuendigung-urlaubsanspruch-pro-rata-temporis/).

Comment: @KarstenKoop: No, you are always entitled to the full amount of days mandated by law, a contract cannot override that (and that's what your article also says). The  contract may have different rules for additional days - that's what I mentioned in my answer under the bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

Company A and B have no relation with each other concerning your holidays. If there are distinct legal entities there is no realistic way to transfer your holidays from one to the other. The only exception I can see would be if A and B are both units from the same bigger company.

In general company A has no interest in paying you for your extra holidays either. You just take the holidays during your last month of employment. If you still have 11.5 days and May is your last month of employment that leaves only 2 or 3 days of actual work left. Hopefully most of the knowledge transfer happened already but that is your employers problem not yours. Talk to HR about what still needs to be done and which days you will show up in the office. Most of the rest of May will be your holiday from Company A.

Comment: Imagine hiring somebody to start work in November, and he decides to take a month of vacation because he didn't took it in his previous company. Whatever the answer is, the new company is not **obliged** to consider "missed" vacation time from other employers.

Comment: hm, the blanket statements of both of you are not correct. Does either of you have experience working in Germany?

Comment: @nvoigt I'm a German working in Germany. I might not know all the laws in full detail but I've never heard of the kind of transfer OP seems to want. My answer just describes how this was handled in every single case I am aware of.

Comment: Well, it's never too late to learn about our great buerocracy  :)

Answer (score 0):

For other countries and in general, if your old company owes you say 15 days of holidays, then you should be able to negotiate with your new company to be able to take 15 days of unpaid holiday. Obviously you take the money for holidays not taken from the old company and use that when you take the unpaid holiday.

Comment: Just to clarify, there is generally no relationship between the two things. You can always try to negotiate with your employer for unpaid leave regardless of the leave situation of your previous employer.

Comment: True, but then you have no money :-(